# Is it possible to run a search cursor on a multipart feature class?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-desktop, select-by-location

I have a multipart feature class of cities.  I want to run a search cursor on a cities feature class where:

1. one city is selected and a select layer by location is run to select all parcels that are within a certain distance X;
2. Values from the selected parcels are then summed together;
3. move on to the next city record

Currently, I am  having trouble getting my select by location statement correct.  Instead of only selecting the parcels that are within distance X of one city, it's selecting all the parcels that are within distance X of all the cities in the feature class.

```
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(city, c_layer)
    cCursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(c_layer)
    print "Created search cursor on c_layer"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(parcel, p_layer)

for row in cCursor:
    geoName = row.getValue("GEO_NAME")
    print geoName
    geoID = row.getValue("GEO_ID")
    print geoID     

    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(p_layer, "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE", c_layer, search_radius, "NEW_SELECTION")
    print "Completed select by location on p_layer"
    y = arcpy.GetCount_management(p_layer)
    print y
```

Comment: I think the easiest solution to this is to convert multipart to single part, so 1 row in your table is 1 city. Use this [tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003r000000) to convert to single part.

Comment: I tried using the multipart to singlepart management on the city layer earlier and it still didn't work.

Comment: OK assuming you are working from single part features, what exactly is search_radius set to? I think it should be in the format of "1000 Meters" and not just "1000". Are your datasets in different projections? For example you are attempting to do a spatial selection from a dataset that is in meter units onto something that is in decimal degrees.

Comment: My search_radius is defined as:

search_distance = "5"
search_units = "METERS"
search_radius = str(search_distance) + " " + search_units

All the files have the same projection.

Comment: what are you doing with geoName and geoID? You get them, print them and appear to do nothing else with them. Also your selectbylocation is within the cursor loop but nothing alters. Did you intend to have the cursor to select a city with the geoID and THEN use that selected point to select parcels within 5m? If so you need to put in a selectbyattribute call before the selectbylocation.

Comment: How many cities are you dealing with?  How many multipart features? Perhaps start by making sure that you are able to use a cursor to simply list each individual city.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this, first you need to select each individual city in your city feature class as you iterate through each row in your cursor. Since ArcGIS geoprocessing only occurs on selected items, once a city is selected, further selections will only occur in relation to selected features.

I'm assuming that each row in your city feature class represents a city, although the discussion of multipart features makes me a little unsure. Whatever the case, the basic idea still holds true. Select whatever represents a city, and then select parcels associated.

If each feature is a unique city, try this code:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(city, c_layer)
cCursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(c_layer)
print "Created search cursor on c_layer"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(parcel, p_layer)

cOIDField = arcpy.Describe (c_layer).OIDFieldName

for row in cCursor:
    geoName = row.getValue("GEO_NAME")
    print geoName
    geoID = row.getValue("GEO_ID")
    print geoID

    #sql statement to select one feature by OID
    sql = '"' + cOIDField + '" = \'' + row.getValue(cOIDField) + "'"
    #select by attribute cities using sql statement
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (c_layer, "", sql)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(p_layer, "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE", c_layer, search_radius, "NEW_SELECTION")
    y = arcpy.GetCount_management(p_layer)
    print y
```

I hope this helps!